# Vue2 with typescript, Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I have the below Vue component:

```
<template>
    <v-snackbar bottom :color="color" v-model="snackbar">
        {{ msg }}
        <v-btn flat @click.native="close()">Close</v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueEvent from '../../VueEvent';

    export default Vue.extend({
        data(): object {
            return {
                snackbar: false,
                msg: '',
                color: '',
            };
        },
        created() {
            VueEvent.listen('snackbar', (data) => {
                this.snackbar = true;
                this.msg = data.msg;
                this.color = data.color;
            });
            this.malert();
        },
        methods: {
            close(): void {
                this.snackbar = false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

When Typescript compiles I get the following error:

```
Property 'snackbar' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, object, { close(): void; }, {}, Readonly<Record<never, any>>>'.
    28 |         methods: {
    29 |             close(): void {
  > 30 |                 this.snackbar = false;
       |                      ^
    31 |             }
    32 |         }
    33 |     });
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem, or explain why its happening?

Comment: Can you declare `close(): void ` as an arrow function?

Comment: I get even more errors then. I can resolve it by doing `(this as any).snackbar` but it should work. I have looked at so  many examples where this is how its done. I am also using the shim as stated in docs

Comment: Maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002310/property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-combinedvueinstancevue-read/68505277#68505277.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't have a good answer for you, but I have theory:

The original type declaration resides in vue/types/options.d.ts:

```
type DefaultData<V> =  object | ((this: V) => object); // here is the kicker
Data=DefaultData<V>
data?: Data;
```

And I found that:

```
data():object { ... // this.snackbar does not exist
data(){ ... // this.snackbar does exist.
data(): any { ... // this.snackbar does exist.
data(): { snackbar: boolean; msg: string; color: string } { ... // Also valid
```

I think without your object declaration typescript will think that  `data` is `DefaultData<V> = object`. But once you say it returns an object, data will suddenly match `((this: V) => object)` instead. Now typescript expects `this` to  be of type `V` (which I assume is a vue-instance) and since that vue instance does not have a snackbar in it's definition, boom, typescript throws.

Lot's of guessing here, but I think pretty much anything *except* explicitly returning `object` would work to not match that second signature in `DefaultData<V>`.

Comment: This solved it, I guess i should really create an interface for my data? Anyway, problem solved, thanks