# Vue-compiler unable to parse "$cookies"

Tags: cookies, vue.js, vue-component

While working with cookies in vue,after installing & importing,

```
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'
Vue.use (VueCookies)
```

The compiler throws the following **error**-

```
Property '$cookies' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance..
```

I have mentioned the cookie statements as mentioned in the official documents, as-

```
this.$cookies.set('user',this.userContents);
```

These cookies work well with the designed flow and does gets stored in the browser.
The only issue is that the compiler is throwing **error** despite the fact that these cookies are interacting as required with the Application.

Thank you

Comment: Do you use Typescript? Have you tried `window.$cookies.set('user', this.userContents);`?

Comment: Yes, I did use Typescript. I tried using window.$cookies.set('user',this.userContents);   but it showed the same error as -  Property 'window' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance...

Comment: Dang, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810291/) helps…

Comment: No, it didn't work @Lars Beck